# Copy value from another table from a group footer

Tags: listlabel

I'm using LL 25, trying to store a value from one table into a variable and then display it in a column in another table.

The values I need to store are being output as group footers.

Is this possible with User Variables or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `GetVar` and `SetVar` functions for this purpose, as long as the value is first stored and then retrieved (i.e. the table referencing the value is printed after the table containing the value).

A simple `SetVar("MyVariable", [ValueToStore])` is all it takes to store the value. Then use `GetVar("MyVariable")` to retrieve it later.

If the order is reversed, i.e. the table containing the variable is printed after the reference, you need to use a multi pass approach. I blogged about this very topic here:

[Finally – a Glance in the Crystal Ball](https://www.combit.blog/en/multi-pass-processing/)

This feature (i.e. the double pass) is available since version 26.`GetVar` and `SetVar` are available in 25 as well.

For older versions, the value can be precalculated and passed as variable/field.

Comment: I'm on Version 25

Comment: You should be fine as long as the value is printed first, then referenced. Otherwise, you'd need to update, unfortunately or precalculate the value in your app and pass it as variable.

Comment: Thanks, pre calculating worked in this case.

Comment: You might consider marking my answer as solution then :)

Comment: Marked as the answer, though technically the answer used came from your comment. 

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood this. Edited the answer to contain this part :). Cheers!